# Tagcanvas with colorbox overlay is throwing IE9 into quirks mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I have implemented a tagcloud onto my webpage, instead of words I am using images and I am calling colorbox to provide a nice styled overlay and a biography of that person.

All of this works correctly in EVERY browser except IE.

I am using another colorbox overlay that does work on that same page, it is not in the tagcanvas area.

I noticed the IE9 Console throwing this at me:

```
HTML1113: Document mode restart from IE9 Standards to Quirks
```

Has anyone seen this before?  Is there a way to stop it from switching to Quirks mode?  I have tried a few different doctypes, even some meta tags like:

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9">
```

Still, no dice!  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your doctype is probably missing an FSI.

> Doctype sniffing works by detecting which of these parts are present in the doctype declaration. If an FPI is present, but an FSI isn’t, browsers generally choose quirks mode, since this was the common way of writing doctype declarations in the old days. Browsers also choose quirks mode if the doctype declaration is missing altogether—which used to be very common—or is malformed.

See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/doctypesniffing